# Initialize modal in new page

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

How can I initialize a new dialog in my new page on load using `$mdDialog.show` by runing it via function invoke in my controller for my new page load instead of action from div by click.
Now dialog is working but I can't close it probably because the event does not work in it.

EDIT:

```
function dialog(/*parameters using by invoke from div*/) {

  var useFullScreen = ($mdMedia('sm') || $mdMedia('xs'));
  $mdDialog.show({
    controller: controller,
    templateUrl: 'temp.html',
    parent: angular.element($document.body),
    targetEvent: ev,
    scope: $scope,
    preserveScope: true,
    clickOutsideToClose:true,
    fullscreen: useFullScreen
  });
}
```

and then I call it in my controller on new page load

```
dialog();
```

the main problem is probably that, I want it invoke from my controller instead of div by ng-click.

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: @Austin question update

Comment: Just write `dialog();` inside your controller? Or `$scope.dialog = function() { dialog(); };`?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte nope mate, this isn't working at all, dialog doesn't close